# change prices in a specific category

Tags: mysql, sql

I can change all the prices in all categories with the following command but I only want to change prices in a specific category but the category info is in another table called categories with a column called categories_id , the category id is 12, ho can I do it? thanks

UPDATE products  SET products_price = REPLACE(products_price, "20","22")

Comment: Can you please share the structure of the `products` and `categories` tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **where** clause to restrict the rows effected

```
  WHERE cat="A"

ex->
  update products set price= replace(price,20,22) where cat="A"
```

you don't need to deal with the cat info table. Hope you have a foreign key field("cat") in main table that will map with the cat info table.

Comment: the structure of products is table products products_price

Comment: the structure of the products table is products products_price and the structure of the categories table is categories with a column called categories_id , the category id is 12

Comment: You have to implement foreign keys first. That's how you should bind two tables together